# Query To Pull Contact Records That Have Been Created In The Last 1 Hour

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

```
SELECT WheelersUsers.user_id,WheelersUsers.email,WheelersUsers.created
FROM WheelersUsers
WHERE ((DATEDIFF(hh,GETDATE(),WheelersUsers.created)* -2 )/2) <= 1
```

And I wanted to know how I can overwrite the records that are already in the resulting table with the new records each time. This is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing Cloud uses a subset of [T-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(v=sql.90).aspx) for [Query Activities](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/). This select statement would return the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT user_id, email, created
FROM WheelersUsers
WHERE DATEDIFF(hh,created,GETDATE()) = 0
```

The GetDate() function returns an integer denoting the time between two dates. In this case, the datepart paramaeter ("hh") stipulates we are looking for the number of hours between our two dates - "created" and now (GetDate()). 59 minutes would return 0 and 60 minutes would return 1.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include more detail about _why_ this soql works?

Comment: It's not soql it's T-SQL